# how to compile an xsd schema (properly validated) in xcode ios7

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios7, xsd

I need to compile in xcode programming an xsd schema and generate a .m model from it. How is it possible? thank you in advance.

EDITED: in Java I use scomp (xmlbeans package) command to create a jar file from xsd schema. Anyone knows anything similar in xcode?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you done a google search even?

Comment: I have been googling for some days but I got nothing really useful.

Comment: this helped me a lot even if no xsd schema is used, a fast way to read from xml 
https://code.google.com/p/wonderxml/